# Unable to return Object[] from DataProvider

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

I tried returning a single dimensional `Object[]` from dataProvider and it worked for me. But the same code is not working in my office environment.What would be the issue?

I am using `TestNG 6.13.1`

```
@DataProvider(name = "Data")
public Object[] dataProvider() throws BiffException, IOException {

    jxl.setExcel("UserDetails", "H:\\Data.xls");
    int rowcount = jxl.getRowCount();
    Object[] data = new Object[rowcount];

    data = jxl.getColumn("Row");//Returns String array

    return data;

}

@Test(dataProvider = "Data")
public void verify(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting now?

Comment: TestNG has always mandated that a `@DataProvider` annotated method would return a 2D Object array or an `Iterator<Object[]>` (in the case of lazy  data driven tests where the data source is too huge to be loaded in one shot or when the data source is a streaming data source). So not sure how it worked for you.

Comment: The same code worked on another system. But it isnt wokring on my company's system. It throws the following error. 
 DataProvider must return either Object[][] or Iterator<Object>[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object t

Comment: Can you please try at your end ? Just pass a String array instead of the JXL